# Clarifying combat damage to player with abilities like Bloodthirst and Cipher

Tags: magic-the-gathering

For cards like [Vampire Outcasts](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=368537) or [Shadow Slice](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=366455), does Bloodthirst/Cipher only activate when combat damage is dealt directly to a player? For example, if an opponent blocks my attacking creature then the combat damage is dealt to the creature and not the "player", correct?

Should I be thinking in terms of since the player and the creature are separate then any combat damage dealt to a creature is not the same as a combat damage dealt to the player?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A player and his or her creatures are separate things. Dealing combat damage to a creature does not count as dealing combat damage to that creature's controller, and vice versa. Also, regarding your last sentence, a player never deals damage to anything, only sources controlled by that player, such as spells and creatures.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I have been playing Bloodthirst incorrectly and activating it when combat damage was dealt to a creature belonging to an opponent. Wasn't sure if it had to be dealt directly to the player.